# Attempting to install Ubuntu 20.04 on IBM zSeries: get message [ 0.388627] Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed

Tags: 20.04

Attempting to install Ubuntu 20.04 on IBM zVM running on IBM z13s processor using downloaded ISO file:
ubuntu-20.04-live-server-s390x.iso
Data extracted from boot subdirectory
initrd.ububtu
kernel.ubuntu
parmfile.ubuntu

Files punched to zVM reader by 'ubuntu exec'

On IPL receive the following messages:

```
ubuntu                                                                          
0000002 FILES PURGED                                                            
RDR FILE 0005 SENT FROM UBUNTU20 PUN WAS 0005 RECS 101K CPY  001 A NOHOLD NOKEEP
RDR FILE 0006 SENT FROM UBUNTU20 PUN WAS 0006 RECS 0001 CPY  001 A NOHOLD NOKEEP
RDR FILE 0007 SENT FROM UBUNTU20 PUN WAS 0007 RECS 324K CPY  001 A NOHOLD NOKEEP
0000003 FILES CHANGED                                                           
0000003 FILES CHANGED                                                           
[    0.388627] Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed                      
ln: /tmp/mountroot-fail-hooks.d//scripts/init-premount/lvm2: No such file or dir
ectory                                                                          


BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6) built-in shell (ash)                 
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.   

(initramfs)  [6nUnable to find a medium containing a live file system         

Installation cannot continue.
```

How can I fix this ??

Answer (score 0):

Previous versions, 16.04 and 18.04 had a ubuntu parmfile that has an X'0A' followed by 79 X'00' characters. When you IPL'ed the kernel loaded and you would be prompted for network configuration info. After replying you could launch an SSH session and continue the installation.

On 20.04, the UBUNTU PARMFILE has the following: 
X'40606060 4098A489 85A32540 4040404'
c'   - - -   q u i  e t  "

If the UBUNTU PARMFILE is replaced with ac copy of the UBUNTU PARMFILE from 128.04, The IPL of the kernel continues but never prompts for network information.

Does everything now have to be specified in the UBUNTU PARMFILE ??

Comment: UBUNTU PARMFILE from 18.04 ..